# What kind of grease can be used on outdoor screws to avoid rust

Tags: screws, rust-proofing

I have fixed some screws outside to mount a house number onto masonry.

I feel like I should probably apply some sort of grease or water repellent to avoid rust as they will be exposed to rain frequently.

What kind of grease should I smear over them to avoid any potential rust over time.

I've done some reading and I keep seeing copper or lithium grease mentioned to preserve bolts, are these right for screws or is there something else?

Comment: FWIW, I use silicone caulk.

Answer (score 4):

Any coating of grease or other rust inhibitor will wear off over time. The right approach is to use fasteners that are corrosion resistent either due to their material (such as stainless or brass), or are plated (with zinc, chrome, or other durable material).

Answer (score 0):

Plain old petroleum jelly (Vaseline). It has so many uses around the house, from inhibiting rust to polishing shoes to removing eye makeup, that it belongs in your tool box next to the duct tape and W-D 40.
;)